# Training & validation accuracy increasing & training loss is decreasing - Validation Loss is NaN

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, loss-function, cross-entropy

I am training a classifier model on [cats vs dogs](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats-redux-kernels-edition/data) data. The model is a minor variant of ResNet18 & returns a softmax probability for classes. However, I am noticing that the **validation loss is majorly NaN** whereas training loss is steadily decreasing & behaves as expected. Training & Validation accuracy increase epoch by epoch.

```
Epoch 1/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1372s 4s/step - loss: 0.7849 - accuracy: 0.5131 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.5343
Epoch 2/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1372s 4s/step - loss: 0.6966 - accuracy: 0.5539 - val_loss: 13989871201999266517090304.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.5619
Epoch 3/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1373s 4s/step - loss: 0.6570 - accuracy: 0.6077 - val_loss: 747123703808.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.5679
Epoch 4/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1372s 4s/step - loss: 0.6180 - accuracy: 0.6483 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.6747
Epoch 5/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1373s 4s/step - loss: 0.5838 - accuracy: 0.6852 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.6240
Epoch 6/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1372s 4s/step - loss: 0.5338 - accuracy: 0.7301 - val_loss: 31236203781405710523301888.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.7590
Epoch 7/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1373s 4s/step - loss: 0.4872 - accuracy: 0.7646 - val_loss: 52170.8672 - val_accuracy: 0.7378
Epoch 8/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1372s 4s/step - loss: 0.4385 - accuracy: 0.7928 - val_loss: 2130819335420217655296.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.8101
Epoch 9/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1373s 4s/step - loss: 0.3966 - accuracy: 0.8206 - val_loss: 116842888.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.7857
Epoch 10/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1372s 4s/step - loss: 0.3643 - accuracy: 0.8391 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.8199
Epoch 11/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1373s 4s/step - loss: 0.3285 - accuracy: 0.8557 - val_loss: 788904.2500 - val_accuracy: 0.8438
Epoch 12/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1372s 4s/step - loss: 0.3029 - accuracy: 0.8670 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.8245
Epoch 13/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1373s 4s/step - loss: 0.2857 - accuracy: 0.8781 - val_loss: 121907.8594 - val_accuracy: 0.8444
Epoch 14/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1373s 4s/step - loss: 0.2585 - accuracy: 0.8891 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.8674
Epoch 15/15
312/312 [==============================] - 1374s 4s/step - loss: 0.2430 - accuracy: 0.8965 - val_loss: 822.7968 - val_accuracy: 0.8776
```

I checked for the following -

- Infinity/NaN in validation data
- Infinity/NaN caused when normalizing data (using `tf.keras.applications.resnet.preprocess_input`)
- If the model is predicting only one class & hence causing loss function to behave oddly

Training code for reference -

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-3)
model = Resnet18(NUM_CLASSES=NUM_CLASSES) # variant of original model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    steps_per_epoch=len(X_train) // BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=valid_dataset,
    validation_steps=len(X_valid) // BATCH_SIZE,
    verbose=1,
)
```

The most relevant answer I found was the last paragraph of the accepted answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282160/how-is-it-possible-that-validation-loss-is-increasing-while-validation-accuracy). However, that doesn't seem to be the case here as validation loss diverges by order of magnitudes compared to training loss & returns nan. Seems like the loss function is misbehaving.

Comment: Model could be suffering from exploding gradient, you can try applying gradient clipping.

Comment: I tried that too by passing the optimizer "clipnorm=1.0", that didn't seem to work either

Comment: How did you split the dataset?

Comment: Stratified train_test_split with test_size=0.2